Cage fight where one fighter tells the other not to hit him in the face
Movie starts out with a cage fight. The man says to the other don't hit me in the face or I will kill you (or he might have said you will never fight again). The winner (very toned and defined but skinny) goes up to an oriental women's room and then paralyzes her somehow. Later in the movie same man shoots a rocket out of moving train and kills some government official. Sorry I can't remember more.  What movie is this?

This could use some more detail if you have it. Like, when did you see it? When was the movie from (did it look like a '70s movie)? English or dubbed? Notable actors?

   [Source]
This sounds like Alex Cross (2012):

... a man (Matthew Fox) participates in an underground ultimate fighting match, where he flirts with businesswoman Fan Yau (Stephanie Jacobsen). 
After brutally beating his opponent, the man is invited to Fan Yau's house. There, he sedates, tortures, and kills her.
[...]
... does not need to be in the area as he fires a bazooka from a moving train,... 


Watch the trailer


Man he looks creepy :p
